# React-Redux action is not being fired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using `React` with `react-redux, redux and redux-actions`.

I have one action that takes the current token stored in localStorage and ensures that it is not expired, like so:

```
export const verifyLogin = () => {
  return verifyLoginAC({
    url: "/verify/",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      token: `${
        localStorage.getItem("token")
          ? localStorage.getItem("token")
          : "not_valid_token"
      }`
    },
    onSuccess: verifiedLogin,
    onFailure: failedLogin
  });
};

function verifiedLogin(data) {
  const user = {
    ...data.user
  }
  setUser(user);
  return {
    type: IS_LOGGED_IN,
    payload: true
  };
}

function failedLogin(data) {
  return {
    type: IS_LOGGED_IN,
    payload: false
  };
}
```

When it verifies the token it returns a response like so:

```
{
  token: "token_data",
  user: {
    username: "this",
    is_staff: true,
    (etc...)
  }
}
```

As you can see in `verifiedLogin()`, it is calling another function (in this case an action creator) to set the user to the user object returned by my API. the setUser is defined like this:

`const setUser = createAction(SET_USER);`

which should create an Action like this:

```
{
  type: SET_USER,
  payload: {
    userdata...
  }
}
```

The reducer is defined like this:

```
import { handleActions } from "redux-actions";
import { SET_USER } from "../constants/actionTypes";

export default handleActions(
  {
    [SET_USER]: (state, action) => action.payload
  },
  {}
);
```

I know the action creator is correct, as I have verified by `console.log(setUser(user));` but all that is in the state is an empty object for users. I am unable to determine why it is not working successfully. I am new to React and Redux so it may be something I misunderstood.

Edit:

This is `apiPayloadCreator`:

```
const noOp = () => ({ type: "NO_OP" });

export const apiPayloadCreator = ({
  url = "/",
  method = "GET",
  onSuccess = noOp,
  onFailure = noOp,
  label = "",
  data = null
}) => {
  console.log(url, method, onSuccess, onFailure, label, data);
  return {
    url,
    method,
    onSuccess,
    onFailure,
    data,
    label
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are calling `setUser`, it is not being **dispatched** by Redux, which is what ultimately executes a reducer and updates the store. Action creators like `setUser` are not automatically wired up to be dispatched; that is done in the `connect` HOC. You will need a Redux middleware such as [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) to dispatch async / multiple actions. Your code can then be something like the example below (using redux-thunk):

```
export const verifyLogin = () => (dispatch) => {
  return verifyLoginAC({
    url: "/verify/",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      token: `${
        localStorage.getItem("token")
          ? localStorage.getItem("token")
          : "not_valid_token"
      }`
    },
    onSuccess: (result) => verifiedLogin(dispatch, result),
    onFailure: (result) => diapatch(failedLogin(result))
  });
};

const verifiedLogin = (dispatch, data) => {
  const user = {
    ...data.user
  };
  dispatch(setUser(user));
  dispatch({
    type: IS_LOGGED_IN,
    payload: true
  });
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I can see the action fire in redux-logger but it has a type of undefined? I researched redux-thunk but I'm still stumped.

Comment: Sorry, after reviewing my code example I saw that I was calling verifiedLogin with incorrect arguments. I've updated my example to pass dispatch as an argument.

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. When I `console.log(action)` from in my api middleware it is receiving the function as the action like literally is returning `verifyLoginAC({...})`. I also tried placing thunk middleware to be applied first but then it never fires at all.

Comment: Another typo... try moving the `dispatch` argument from the first set of parenthesis to the second on the `verifyLogin` line as in the updated example. This is what I get for typing code examples while on vacation and my brain is shut off. If this doesn't work for you I will write up a more complete CodeSandbox example.

Comment: I wrote a quick, executable example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wkl5x9pz18) that uses redux-thunk with the function names from your question. You will still see the inner function get logged by redux-logger, but redux-thunk intercepts that and invokes it with `dispatch` and `getState` as arguments. In the CodeSandbox example you will see how this original function is logged as an action and followed shortly after by the actions pass to `dispatch`.

Comment: I think why it is not working is that my API is not firing. when i console.log the action object it receives it is `f(dispatch) verifyLoginAC({...})`, so before it sends an API request it checks if `action.type == API` but because action is a function it is not firing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181220/discussion-between-chbresser-and-tyler).

Comment: As you did answer my question on why the action is not being fired I am going to mark yours as the answer. I know see that it may be my API interfering and I will post a new Question for that as it is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to use something like `redux-thunk` in order to do async actions. See [the documentation](https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions#async-action-creators) on how this is done.

Comment: I'll be honest Tom, I am a little confused. It looks like `redux-thunk` allows you to use functions instead of action objects, but I am only trying to return action objects.

Comment: Redux is synchronous by design. It does not wait for a response. It expects an immediate return of an object `{ type: ..., payload: ... }` instead of a `Promise`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise. Therefore, you need to use some middleware to handle async actions (that eventually resolve to return `object`s), as explained in the Redux docs: https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions#async-action-creators